# VBA: Clearing an entire row based on a cell value automatically

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially, I have a macro that when a value is put in a cell in column B it updates the rest of the information in the other columns. When I delete that value in column B I want the rest of the information in the other columns to be deleted.

The code I am using is similar to the below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("B:B")

        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
               Is Nothing Then

           If Range(Target.Address).Value = "X" Then
              Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = "1"
              Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value = "2"
              Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = "3"
              Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value = "4"
              End If
        EndIf

End Sub
```

The long way is to do another if statement:

```
 If Range(Target.Address).Value = "" Then
   Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
   Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
   Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
   Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
   End If
```

Since the macro runs automatically, this will do the job. Is there a way to do it with clear.contents?

Comment: try range(target.offset(0,1),target.offset(0,4).clearcontents

Comment: Also there is no need to type range(target.address) it is the same as simple typing target.  so the the line: If Range(Target.Address).Value = "X" Then, would be: If Target.Value = "X" then.

Comment: I see what you are saying Scott, however I believe this will conflict with my first "IF" statement. Which is stating one cell and the column. Target would have me compare a column with a column which is why I need address to narrow my scope to a singular cell. Your solution did work with a little editing though:                                                                           If Range(Target.Address).Value = "" Then
       Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), Target.Offset(0, 4)).ClearContents    End If    Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I would have done it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        If Target.Value = "x" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = "1"
            Target.Offset(0, 2) = "2"
            Target.Offset(0, 3) = "3"
            Target.Offset(0, 4) = "4"
        Else
            Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), Target.Offset(0, 4)).ClearContents
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, I see now. I'll give that a try later on and let you know how it worked on my version, which is a little more complex.

Comment: Very good, it works. Hopefully other users find this solution. One of the better answers I've seen on stack overflow!

Comment: @UserX I am glad I was able to help.  Also feel free to mark this as a correct answer.